# Integration Tests for Web API Controller is giving the following error: Type 'XXXController' does not have a default constructor

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

Full error message:

```
{
    "Message":"An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage":"Type 'XXXController' does not have a default constructor",
    "ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException",
    "StackTrace":"   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
}
```

I've done a bit of Googling and am now stuck on what to try next.

I've installed a `NinjectDependencyResolver` via:

```
PM> Install-Package Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver
```

And am using the following code in a `TestInitialize` method to create an `HttpClient`:

```
 var kernel = new StandardKernel(/* ... */);

var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(BaseAddress);

/* ... */

config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

_client = new HttpClient(new HttpServer(config));
```

And then am issuing a `PostAsync` request on the client.  The result's content has the error at the top.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While typing this question I double-checked and noticed that I wasn't passing in one of my `NinjectModule`'s into the `StandardKernel`.  Adding that module that registered the types being passed into the constructor solved that exception.  If I was missing a binding for a type I was expecting that to say something else (Like "Could not find a binding for `IMyInterface`").